# Bootstrap vertical writing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-text

I want to write text with Bootstrap, vertically but not like transform the text 90°. Vertical, but turned and hard to read.

[image]

But actually written like this: Vertical and not turned

[image]

I think there was a way to do this with Bootstrap? Do you know something?

Comment: I believe that Bootstrap does not provide such functionality. I guess there would be a CSS-only solution.

Comment: Also, a google search on the topic returns a bunch of examples e.g. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-easiest-way-to-create-vertical-text-with-css--net-15284

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
CSS
      .verticaltext{
           width:1px;
           word-wrap: break-word;
           white-space:pre-wrap; 
        }
```

Comment: Thanks you. However it's a CSS hack, use it responsibly

Answer (score 9):

```
writing-mode: vertical-rl;
text-orientation: mixed;

// or

writing-mode: vertical-rl;
text-orientation: upright;
```

Also try these values

```
/* Keyword values */
text-orientation: mixed;
text-orientation: upright;
text-orientation: sideways-right;
text-orientation: sideways;
text-orientation: use-glyph-orientation;

/* Global values */
text-orientation: inherit;
text-orientation: initial;
text-orientation: unset;
```

Answer (score 7):

You may want to see this tutorial! 
https://davidwalsh.name/css-vertical-text

In simplicity, you can use CSS to do this.

```
.vertical-text {
transform: rotate(90deg);
transform-origin: left top 0;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

There is absolutely no specific way in Bootstrap nor in CSS alone to write in his particular way ...

I guess the only way to do that kind of thing is to make a return to the line after every letter. Try the HTML `<br>` tag for example. The major issue with that kind of technique is semantics, considering the word will be split.

Comment: Please no use <br>! Don't use HTML for styling the web page!

Comment: This answer is simply wrong and should probably be deleted.